# JavaScript expression merging instead of adding variables

Tags: javascript

I have a simple equation that uses variables, but it appears to merge together as a string instead of calculating the formula as follows:

```
var mydimensions = "10x9x8";
var splitDimensions = mydimensions.split("x");
var lengthDimension = splitDimensions[0];
var widthDimension = splitDimensions[1]; 
var depthDimension = splitDimensions[2];
var score = 0.25

var myvalue = (widthDimension * .5) + depthDimension + score;

//logged value 4.580.25
```

However, if I try the equation without the variables, it works as follows:

```
var myvalue = (9 * .5) + 8 + .25;

//logged value = 12.75
```

How do I get it to calculate the variable values instead of treating it as a string?

Comment: Make sure none of your variables are a string on the way in. Especially check the `depthDimension` one.

Comment: If they are, how should I convert them?

Comment: I would recommend `parseFloat`, unless you know they'll be integers (then `parseInt`).

Comment: I obtain 12.75. If they are string, convert them with parseInt(depthDimension, 10) method

Comment: Affixing .0 to the dimension variables will fix it, but this is strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What browser are you using?  I just tried it on Chrome and got the correct result of 12.75

If your variables are set as Strings, which is likely the issue here, convert them to numerical values.

You have three options:

1. Use the function `parseFloat()` (or `parseInt()` for Integer values)
2. Add the plus sign before the variables, so instead of `widthDimension` write `+widthDimension`
3. Use the `Number()` function, e.g. `Number(widthDimension)` (as noted by Sterling Archer in the comments)

Comment: `Number(widthDimension);` is also a valid conversion

Comment: @SterlingArcher - updated answer to reflect that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the source code is as you provided, both will yield 12.75.
If you have the source of the value of variable uncertain, you can use Number() function to force it to be a number.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, after careful consideration of downstream impacts/code reuse, I converted the strings to int's as follows (They were returning a string not an int):

```
var mydimensions = "10x9x8";
var splitDimensions = mydimensions.split("x");
var lengthDimension = parseInt(splitDimensions[0],10);
var widthDimension = parseInt(splitDimensions[1],10);
var depthDimension = parseInt(splitDimensions[2],10);
```

Comment: You should have posted this right off, it is obvious what the problem is here.

Comment: Apologies, I oversimplified the issue

Comment: Base 10 is the default for parseInt(), so there is no need to include ",10" there.